# How to "mask" an input to show brazilian currency

Tags: javascript, html

I need a input range shows the value formatted for Brazilian money.
By logic, it would suffice to receive this number in a function that would format it and then return the formatted value. But this is Javascript, and I found no way to make it work.

```js
function converter(valor){
  var numero = (valor).toLocaleString('pt-BR');
  document.getElementById('valor').value = 'R$ '+numero;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="4000.00" value="2000.00" step="0.01" style="width:100%" oninput="converter(this.value)">
<p>
<input type="text" name="valor" value="R$ 0,00" id="valor">
```

Comment: There's <script> tags that are breaking it, I edited your question to fix that

Comment: What is the problem you have with your current code?

Comment: The problem is when I use an "input range" the "toLocaleString" function does NOT work, although it works normally in other cases.

Comment: Here in Brazil, we use the currency value thus: R$ 1.349,47. That is, the comma (,) separates the decimals and the period (.) Separates the thousands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of the `toLocaleString()` that is the `options` style argument, where you can set the currency, so you don't even need to use the concatenation with `"R$"` because it will be ready when `toLocaleString` is called.

Note that it's not current working for you because `toLocaleString()` is part of the `Number.prototype` in javascript and the parameter `valor` that you have is a string, so it won't work if you don't parse the string to number.

See below.

```js
function converter(valor){
  var numero = parseFloat(valor).toLocaleString('pt-BR',{ style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
  document.getElementById('valor').value = numero;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="4000.00" value="2000.00" step="0.01" style="width:100%" oninput="converter(this.value)">
<p>
<input type="text" name="valor" value="R$ 0,00" id="valor">
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Very grateful for your solution. Is there any way to insert a SPACE between the currency symbol (R$) and the number, so that "R$1.439,47" is thus "R$ 1.439,47"?
If it does not, that's fine, this has already solved the problem. thanks

Comment: I don't know for you, but for me it is showing with a space, like this `R$ 1.439,47`. If for you it's not, then you maybe need to remove the second parameter of `toLocaleString` and do the concatenation as you were doing before. (don't forgetting to parse to number)

Comment: Adjusted, so the space appears:
function converte(valor){
var numero = parseFloat(valor).toLocaleString('pt-BR',{ currency: 'BRL' });
document.getElementById(valor').value = 'R$ '+numero;
}
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are doing it with ReactJS I would suggest you to take a look in this component. You also could wrap it in a custom component e.g.component={TextField}

```
import React from "react"
import IntlCurrencyInput from "react-intl-currency-input"

const currencyConfig = {
  locale: "pt-BR",
  formats: {
    number: {
      BRL: {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "BRL",
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2,
      },
    },
  },
};

const BrlCurrencyComponent = () => {
  const handleChange = (event, value, maskedValue) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(value); // value without mask (ex: 1234.56)
    console.log(maskedValue); // masked value (ex: R$1234,56)
  };

  return(
    <IntlCurrencyInput 
      component={TextField}
      currency="BRL" 
      config={currencyConfig}
      onChange={handleChange} 
    />
  );
}

export default BrlCurrencyComponent;
```

[image]

[Here is the github link](https://Here%20is%20the%20github%20link%20%20%20%5B%5C%5B1%5C%5D:%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSGom.gif%5D%5B1%5D)